# System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, system.net.webexception, webexception

Getting following error in xamarin: System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.)

Below is my code:

```
            UserRepository usr = new UserRepository();
            var restClient = usr.RestClient;         //rest client code
            restClient.BaseUrl = StdAppIds.webServerUrl;
            var restRequest = new RestRequest();
            restRequest.Resource = "/GetVersion";
            restRequest.Method = HttpMethod.POST;
            var response = await restClient.ExecutePostAsync(restRequest);  //rest request
```

Comment: @Saamer that is a very bad recommendation for Android and has been for a long time.

Comment: My bad, didn't know that. Shubham could you try different "Http Implementation" methods in your android settings and see if it fixes anything?